# Speeding up Cython. Lists vs Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, cython

I am currently trying to speed up a Cython routine which relies heavily on lists. Mostly, I would like to increase the speed up the indexing on these lists.

According to the documentation, it is recomended to use Numpy arrays with memoryviews.

https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

However, when I change my lists to numpy arrays (Most of them are just integers), the code becomes way slower. 
I would like to understand better why this happens, since I would expect that arrays would be much faster than lists.

I cannot show the exact code that I am working on but I will use an example to convey my problem.

So lets say I have these three functions, that counts the number of elements in a list.
Example: if the list is:

```py
test_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4]
```

then the output is [3, 1, 2, 2].

```py
def counter(test_list):
""" The Counter was imported from collections naturally """
    output = [0] * len(set(test_list))
    for key, value in Counter(test_list).items():
        output[key - 1] = value
    return output
```

Now two cython functions that compute the same things:

```
def cython_counter_collections(test_list):

    cdef int key, value

    output = [0] * len(set(test_list))
    for key, value in Counter(test_list).items():
        output[key - 1] = value
    return output
```

and

```py
def cython_counter_manual(test_list):

    cdef long[:] new_test_list = np.array(test_list)
    cdef int size, val, i, uniques_size
    size = new_test_list.shape[0]
    uniques_size = np.unique(new_test_list).shape[0]

    i = 0
    output = [0] * uniques_size
    while i < size:
        val = new_test_list[i]
        output[val-1] += 1
        i+=1

    return output
```

For the last function I used import and cimport numpy as np.

I would assume the last function, cython_counter_manual, would be the fasted since I use a numpy array and I don't use any Python calls. 
I measure the times using timeit for example like this

```py
print(timeit("counter(test_list)", globals=globals(), number=n_its))
```

for all the functions and the results are:

```
Python Code
3.12014272399756 s

Cython Counter Collections
2.883361326999875 s

Cython Counter Manual
11.205707081000583 s
```

Why does this happen? How did it become so much slower?
Thank you!

Comment: I'd think `np.unique` and `set` use quite different algorithms. I'd guess the majority of different is there. These numbers look pretty similar to [this link](https://bbengfort.github.io/observations/2017/05/02/python-unique-benchmark.html) that a quick google search turned up.

Comment: But according to my understanding, isn't Cython supposed to optimize the numpy operations if you cimport numpy? That was the reason that I though it would be faster.

Comment: No. Cython mostly speeds up indexing individual elements of Numpy arrays (so element-by-element loops become quick). Simply calling an existing function isn't changed - `np.unique` runs at exactly the same speed if called from Python or Cython.